# Jetpack Compose: Update Icon based on Room database query result

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

My app displays an object queried with Retrofit that a user can save to the local `Room` database by tapping an icon. The icon itself works, but if I restart the app the icon's boolean value is set to false even though the object is saved in the database.

How can I check if the object is already in the database and initialize the icon's state?

This is the code I have so far:

`Icon Composable`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FavoriteButton(
    apod: Apod,
    viewModel: ApodViewModel,
    color: Color = Color.White
) {
    var isFavorite by remember { mutableStateOf(viewModel.apodExists.value) }

    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isFavorite,
        onCheckedChange = {
            isFavorite = !isFavorite
            if (isFavorite) {
                viewModel.addApod(apod)
            } else {
                viewModel.removeApod(apod)
            }
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            tint = color,
            imageVector = if (isFavorite) {
                Icons.Filled.Favorite
            } else {
                Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder
            },
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ApodViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    private val readAllData: LiveData<List<Apod>>
    private val repository: ApodRepository

    private val _apodExists = MutableLiveData(false)
    val apodExists: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _apodExists

    init {
        val apodDao = ApodDatabase.getDatabase(application).apodDao()
        repository = ApodRepository(apodDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun apodExists(apod: Apod) {
        _apodExists.postValue(repository.getApodByDate(apod.date) != null)
    }

    fun addApod(apod: Apod) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (repository.getApodByDate(apod.date) == null) {
                repository.addApod(apod)
                Log.d("ApodViewModel", "Apod saved to database")
            } else {
                Log.d("ApodViewModel", "Apod already exists in database")
            }
        }
    }

    fun removeApod(apod: Apod) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (repository.getApodByDate(apod.date) != null) {
                repository.removeApod(apod)
                Log.d("ApodViewModel", "Apod deleted from database")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm struggeling with actually calling the `apodExists()` since I have to do it in the composable from the main thread. If I call it from the composable it keeps throwing me an error that I can't call it from the main thread. Where do I have to call apodExists(apod) to make it work?

Comment: Use `observeAsState` to collect live data value. Also I don't see any calls of `apodExists` that could've update it.

Answer (score -1):

You are expecting to read a value from the database synchronously, which is not something you should do.

This is the age old issue of asynchronous data loading - what you should do is expose a state from your viewmodel with a `loading` flag that is initially set to `true`, and then load the database entry in a coroutine. When you have loaded the value, you update your state to set the `loading` flag to `false` and provide the value that indicates if the database is populated or not.

In your composable you would check the value of the `loading` flag and display a progress indicator or any other placeholder of your choosing and, once the `loading` toggles to `false` you can update your UI to show the correct value based on the database read.